# Перетащить окно папки от пункта А до Б автоматически с помощью python

Tags: python, windows

Я хочу понять возможно ли с помощью Python перетащить окно попки с пункта А до Б. Я имею введу как с помощью мышки мы можем перетащить окно папки к левому углу или к правому угло.
Сейчас мне нужно чтобы Python автомачиски сделал это и перетащил окно папки к левому углу монитора.

Если это возможно подскажите пожалуста как можно сделать.

Comment: А что вы пробовали сделать? Смотрите в сторону `win32gui.MoveWindow()`

Comment: Да, кстати, смешная опечатка у вас - "окно попки" )))

Comment: Попробуйте pyautogui, если надо именно мышкой передвинуть в левый угол (0, 0)
или правый (w, 0)